# Capture Windchill events

Tags: events, ptc-windchill

I am using windchill 11.1 M020, what's the best way to capture events from windchill?

the context is I am a third party java application which runs in a different host than windchill and I'd like to be triggered when Checkin events or version changed happen or any other events

I did some research and here's what I found

- We can Capture events through [custom service listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429038/how-to-capture-revision-event-of-wtobject), but this method not clean enough since we need to develop a custom service code and place it (run it with assigned port) inside windchill container.
- We can capture windchill events through Windchill ESI service and Info*Engine but not sure how to configure ESI to listen to events and publish events to a broker, for example MQ Broker, I don't want to use EMS to avoid any licence.

any recommendations to capture events and publish them to messaging broker?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to capture events from Windchill, is implementing a listener. In Windchill you can implement a service that can be notified from Windchill when objects change their state or when they have been checked in, etc.
As a Windchill service your code runs in process of the Windchill method server so you have to devise some way to comunicate what's happened in Windchill. You could use a web service, a REST call, you can write in a shared log file or something like that.

You can look at this PTC Community (Windchill Discussions) to start to dig in making Windchill listeners:

https://community.ptc.com/t5/Windchill/How-to-implement-listeners/td-p/674877